# Telling OCaml where opam packages are

Tags: ocaml, development-environment, opam

I am pretty new to OCaml. I have tried installing it from scratch on two different computers -- both Linux Mint -- and encountered this problem both times.

When I install a package with opam (specifically, Base, but it also happens with Core), OCaml can't find it.

```
$ opam install Base
[NOTE] Package base is already installed (current version is v0.11.1).
$ ocaml -open Base
    OCaml version 4.05.0

File "command line", line 1:
Error: Unbound module Base
```

ocaml seems to be in /usr/lib/ocaml and its binaries in /usr/bin/, while opam seems to put everything in ~/.opam/packages.

How do I get OCaml to see the packages installed with opam? I've found many Q&A errors involving unbound modules, but none seem to fix it for me, or they seemed out of date. Also, I know my package manager OCaml is not completely up to date, but I installed 4.10.0 from source too and still had the problem.

Comment: Modules like `Base` are not visible as is to the `ocaml` command. You'll need to use the Dune build tool to set up a project which tells `ocaml` where to find installed packages and their modules. See https://dune.build/ for a quick start example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell the OCaml compiler where your Opam packages are by passing the location of the libraries:

```
ocamlopt -I /path/to/lib/base /path/to/lib/base/base.cmxa helloword.ml
```

In the case of a library like `base`, finding all the parameters might become tedious due to the various dependencies. So, you can instead use the `ocamlfind` wrapper to pass the parameters for you:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package base -linkpkg helloword.ml
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! (I think I had to 'opam install ocamlfind'). A similar one-liner using ocamlbuild was given by ivg and also worked.

Answer (score 1):

The fix suggested in the comments by Yawar worked for me. I installed dune with

```
$ opam install dune
```

Then I executed

```
$ eval $(opam config env)
```

in order to get opam set up in my terminal. (I seem to need to run this every time I open a terminal, despite saying yes to all opam installs, so I will probably add it to ~/.profile.)

The file myproject/helloworld.ml (note no need for "open Base")

```
Base.Printf.ifprintf "Hello, World\n"  (* doesn't actually print anything *)
```

The file myproject/dune

```
(executable
  (name helloworld)
  (libraries base))
```

Then I ran

```
$ dune build helloworld.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the spectrum of answers, if you need to load an installed package into the OCaml interactive toplevel, aka `REPL`, aka the `ocaml` utility (or `utop`), you can issue the following commands after you start `ocaml`<sup>1</sup>

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "base";;
```

Then you can do `open Base` (which will just open the namespace) and use other modules provided by the `base` library.

The `topfind` facility might not be installed on a fresh opam switch, so make sure it is there by

```
opam install ocamlfind
```

Also, to fastly build a simple application, instead of dune you can use ocamlbuild, e.g., given that the code of the main binary is in the file `example.ml` and that you want to use the `base` library,

```
ocamlbuild -package base example.native
```

---

<sup>1</sup>) The `#` character here is a part of the input, not the prompt, i.e., you have to type it, so it will look like

```
# #use "topfind";;
```

Comment: Thanks! Both these solutions worked for me -- the REPL #use #require solution, and also the compiling ocamlbuild solution (I had to "opam install ocamlbuild" as well).

Comment: @usul just a note, don't use ocamlbuild, use Dune. The latter is recommended in the OCaml community. In fact, even the ocamlbuild readme recommends using Dune instead.

Comment: @usul, Just a note, it is totally fine to use ocamlbuild, especially for simple projects and one-shot binaries, there is totally no need to use the heavy artillery like dune. There is nothing wrong with ocamlbuild it served us for many years, is supported, and will server further. There are also omake, oasis, and many other automation tools some are better some are worse, but let's not start, SO is not for recommending the tools or programs, it's about using them.

Comment: Thanks to both for these perspectives!